# Vim: Easy way to convert recorded macro into let

Tags: vim, macros, let

I want to save a certain macro permanently so that I can replay it in future sessions.

For instance, I record the macro which surrounds selected words with `**` (like `**this text is strong**`):

1. Switch to the visual mode
2. Select some words
3. Start recording "a"
4. Press `c`, `**`, `Ctrl-r`, `"`, `**`, `Ctrl-;` (to switch to the normal mode); and
5. Stop recording.

From the next time, I can just select words and press `@a` to replay these actions.

Now I enter `:reg a` and see this output:

```
--- Registers ---
"a   c**^R"**^[
```

How can I define this using the `:let` function so that I can add this to .vimrc and make this macro permanent?

```
:let @a='c**^R"**^['
```

didn't work.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

The `^R` and `^[` in the output of `:reg a` are literal control codes, not `^` followed by `R` or by `[`. Usually, Vim uses a special color to hint at that difference.

You can do either of two things…

- In your `vimrc`, type out the macro directly, using `:help i_ctrl-v` to insert the literal control codes. That is, press `<C-v>` then `<C-r>` to insert a literal `^R`:

  ```
  let @a = 'c**    " type this out
  <C-v><C-r>       " press <C-v><C-r> to insert ^R
  "**              " type this out
  <C-v><Esc>       " press <C-v><Esc> to insert ^[
  '                " type this out
  <Esc>            " leave insert mode
  ```

  [image: result]
- In your `vimrc`, insert the register directly between the quotes with `:help i_ctrl-r`:

  ```
  let @a = '
  <C-r>a
  '
  <Esc>
  ```

Note that it doesn't protect the register in any way so `@a` can be overwritten  accidentally. A mapping, the right hand side of which is a macro, seems safer to me:

```
" again, use <C-v><C-r> to insert `^R`
xnoremap <key> c**^R"**^[

" or use the angled brackets notation
xnoremap <key> c**<C-r>"**<Esc>
```

Comment: It worked. You can remove ```:help``` from "Ctrl-v in the insert mode". ^R were not just a hat and R but ```Ctrl-v``` ```Ctrl-r``` in the insert mode indeed.

Comment: So I guess there's no easy way to do it? Like an encode / decoder for escape characters function that would read the text ^[ and put ESC in. Something like macro2string and string2macro.  If I call this made up function string2macro for example then maybe you could. 
:call setreg('a', string2macro('c**^R"**^[') )   This would make it possible to paste the register as a string and then easily get it back into the register and be able to run the macro.